# store custom WP table names in a global variable

Tags: wpdb, globals

I was being creative and put this in one of the files loaded with my plugin.   Are there implications with storing the table names this way?

```
global $wpdb;

if(!defined('DB_ARTISTS'))
    define('DB_ARTISTS', $wpdb->prefix . "artists");

if(!defined('DB_RELEASES'))
    define('DB_RELEASES', $wpdb->prefix . "releases");
```

EDIT:  I had originally not included all of the information I had meant to.  Tables and variables are prefixed with ABC ( `ABC_DB_ARTISTS` & `$wpdb->prefix . 'abc_artists'` ).

Comment: It will have issues on multisite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DB_` constant prefix in WordPress is generally considered reserved for `DB_NAME`, `DB_HOST`, `DB_USER` and `DB_PASS`. Using it for plugin-specific constants is, in my opinion, not a great idea. The only implication it might pose is if other plugins try to use the constants, but that's purely theoretical.

The proper way to do this is to store the table names in the WPDB object stored in the global `$wpdb`.

```
global $wpdb;

if ( ! isset( $wpdb->myplugin_artists ) && ! isset( $wpdb->myplugin_releases ) ) {
    $wpdb->myplugin_artists = $wpdb->prefix . 'myplugin_artists';
    $wpdb->myplugin_releases = $wpdb->prefix . 'myplugin_releases';
}
```

It's important to use a proper prefix (in this case `myplugin_` for your plugin). For example, for Advanced Custom Fields, this is usually `acf_` ([more on prefixing](http://nacin.com/2010/05/11/in-wordpress-prefix-everything/)).

Comment: I removed my prefixes when posting this.  I shouldn't have, clearly.  I prefixed the DB_ARTISTS constant as well.  Using your method above, I would still need to call global $wpdb every time I wanted to access a table name, so I don't know how much it makes, if anything easier.

Comment: It doesn't make anything any easier, I'm not trying to make your life easier :-). I'm answering your question, "Are there implications with storing the table names this way?" :-).

Comment: to summarize then, there aren't any, but there could be, so I shouldn't do it.  Thanks :)

Comment: Exactly and no problem!